# Import Freebase into OrientDB

Tags: freebase, orientdb

i want to work with relation detection and for that i need a huge
amount of data. i found the freebase dataset and was wondering 
if there is any importer for orient db.

i prefer a java based importer but any script is also welcome.

if i have to code an importer on my own it would be great, if
someone has an idea how to do it on a short and effective way.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any OrientDB importer that I'm aware of but it should be possible to write one. Have you seen this discussion thread from the OrientDB mailings list?

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/orient-database/Wn-KPfq838g/PZ5_SdjEKR4J

The Freebase RDF data dumps are formatted using the same N-Triples format that that sample code uses so it should be easy to adapt that code to work with Freebase data. Please let me know when you get it working. It would be really helpful if you could share your code.

Comment: Yes they are working with triples too but you cant simply import the triples like that because i need to create the schema first. If you have this subject for example: `<http://www4.wiwiss.fu-berlin.de/bizer/bsbm/v01/instances/ProductType1>` You have first the base url. After that `bizer` this is a Vertex and `bsbm` is a subvertex of `bizer`and so on. If you import the data like they did, the schema isnt created. If there is really no importer yet i will code my own and will post it when everything is working.

Comment: Freebase has around 2,000 types of entities which do not have strict inheritance relationships. Any topic in Freebase can have one or more of these types applied to them. From what I understand you can't have multiple types in OrientDB unless they're part of an inheritance tree. What you'll probably have to do is create a single schema-less class called topic which has a property called type.object.type which can then have multiple values.